# How to know which macro is assigned to a certain toolbar button in Word 2003

Tags: vba, macros, toolbar, microsoft-word-2003

I have a Word 2003 toolbar made by someone else long time ago. The toolbar contains lots of buttons and assigned macros.

Until now I have been able to set breakpoints in the VBA code in order to figure out which macros are run, but for one button in my toolbar I have a problem. There does not seem to be any corresponding macro. When I click on the toolbar button, Word also says "The macro cannot be found ..."). My breakpoint finding strategy doesn't seem to a winning concept here.

I am very well aware of this: Tools menu > Customize > Right click on the specific toolbar button:

[image: Tools menu > Customize > Right click on the specific toolbar button]

Unfortunately this doesn't help me. Can I, somehow, see callback event properties for a certain toolbar button? I need to know which macro a certain button is intended to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prints out all macro names which are assigned to any menu button

```
Sub ReadBack_Buttons()
    On Error Resume Next        
    '## Loop through every menu bar
    For Each bar In Application.CommandBars        
        '## Loop through every button on the current menu bar
        For Each button In bar.Controls            
            '## If a macro is assigned, print it out
            If button.OnAction <> "" Then Debug.Print button.Caption & " = " & button.OnAction                
            '## Loop through every button on dropdown menus
            For Each subbutton In button.Controls                
                '## If a macro is assigned, print it out
                If subbutton.OnAction <> "" Then Debug.Print subbutton.Caption & " = " & subbutton.OnAction                    
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

For a quick test, add your own custom menu with this second macro.

```
Sub CreateCommandBar()
    On Error Resume Next        
'## Delete the commandbar if it exists
    Application.CommandBars("example").Delete       
'## Create a new Command Bar
    Set bar = CommandBars.Add(Name:="example", Position:=msoBarFloating)
    bar.Visible = True       
'## Add popup menu
    Set menu1 = bar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    menu1.Caption = "My custom menu"       
'## Add button 1 to popup menu
    Set Btn2 = menu1.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    Btn2.Caption = "missing macro assigned"
    Btn2.OnAction = "Not_working_dummy"       
'## Add button 2 to popup menu
    Set Btn2 = menu1.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    Btn2.Caption = "Hello World"
    Btn2.OnAction = "Hello_world"        
End Sub

Sub Hello_world()
    MsgBox "Hey, it works"
End Sub
```

---

After you've executed `CreateCommandBar` you will see a new entry on your main menu. One with a working macro assigned and one without

[image]

Now, run the first macro `ReadBack_Buttons` and have a look at the immediate pane

```
missing macro assigned = Not_working_dummy  
Hello World = Hello_world
```

Comment: Hmmm... Does this method also work if the toolbar (`CommandBar`) was made at design time? (I mean: Using the toolbar designer tool in **Word 2003**?) I have full access to the entire VBA code in the **Word 2003** template. Unfortunately there is nothing like `CommandBars(index).Controls.xxx`

Comment: @HaunsTM Oh sorry, I confused Excel and Word. Fixed it and worked out a better solution. Hope this helps

Comment: Just tried this as I believe to have (almost) the same problem: I created a custom menu item In Word a long time ago that has a macro associated to it. Now I need to find out which macro this is. I just tried the above macro Sub ReadBack_Buttons(), however this does not produce any output at all (in Word 2003).